# R Programming random prices and aligning them in a table

Tags: r, 3d, diagram, data-analysis

As still in junior level in R programming I am trying to finish my first project.

I have those data (2000 values) (Dft is dry film thickess)

```
Quarter DFT
1st 1,61
1st 2,35
1st 1,74
2nd 2,56
2nd 1,79
2nd 1,84
2nd 1,69
3rd 1,85
3rd 1,73
3rd 2,62
3rd 2,43
3rd 1,85
```

What I want is to produce a vector of random values of a specific area, lets say 0 to 3 (which actually is meters) and those values will be assigned in the existing table with the criteria :

The nearest to 0 the lowest the DFT value.

This way I will create a diagram DFT - Meter with 4 lines regarding the quarter.

The second question can be how this diagramme can be in 3d so I will have a visualize of a pipeline as a cylinder with the different thickness which actually would need the perimeter as well instead of the name "Quarter"

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer for the first part of the question:

Sort your data by column `DFT`:

```
df <- df[order(df$DFT),]

> df
   Quarter  DFT
1      1st 1,61
7      2nd 1,69
9      3rd 1,73
3      1st 1,74
5      2nd 1,79
6      2nd 1,84
8      3rd 1,85
12     3rd 1,85
2      1st 2,35
11     3rd 2,43
4      2nd 2,56
10     3rd 2,62
```

Now generate a random uniformly distributed vector of length 12 with minimum 0 and maximum 3, `sort` it and bind it to your data:

```
df$rand <- sort(runif(12, 0, 3))

> df
   Quarter  DFT      rand
1      1st 1,61 0.3421256
7      2nd 1,69 0.3853747
9      3rd 1,73 1.3841690
3      1st 1,74 1.4411375
5      2nd 1,79 1.5034130
6      2nd 1,84 1.6584415
8      3rd 1,85 2.1692523
12     3rd 1,85 2.6551129
2      1st 2,35 2.6630062
11     3rd 2,43 2.7236042
4      2nd 2,56 2.8132505
10     3rd 2,62 2.8572364
```

Voila. Or should the value of the random variable functionally depend on `DFT`? If so, you would need to provide a distribution function.